# Android Tool: layoutopt

Tags: android

I am a rookie Android Application Developer.  I wanted to start fooling around with the Android SDK tool: layoutopt.  When I ran layoutopt from the command prompt on my Windows 7 machine, I received the following warning and error messages:

WARNING: Java not found in your path.
Checking it it's installed in C:\Program Files\Java instead.

ERROR: No suitable Java found. In order to properly use the Android Developer
Tools, you need a suitable version of Java installed on your system.

This is very frustrating because I know I have downloaded the most recent version of Java, which I double checked after I received this message.  Has anyone else had this issue?  Is it a matter of where I have my Java folder and android-sdk-windows/tools folders relative to each other.  I have experimented with moving the android-sdk-windows directory into the Java directory with no success.

If anyone can help me with what feels like a very silly problem, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add some environment variables like path Java home etc

Answer (score 0):

You can open command prompt and navigate to your android-sdk-windows/tools folder. Than you can use layoutopt like this:
layoutopt main.xml
or layoutopt c:\folder\another\asd.xml